# SQL Server connection via LAN IP in windows Form

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I want to connect my Windows Forms application via local area network. I want to enable database access via the Windows Forms application over the LAN. I have tried different connection string but it is connecting except this string:

```
string sqlConnectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DMStorage;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

The above string works fine to connect but if I try to access the database with a local ip address it failed to reach the server. Here are the strings that I have tried. I am using sql server 2022.

```cs
//string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source = 192.9.210.62,1433; Initial Catalog = DM_Storage;Trusted_Connection=True;";
//string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source = 192.9.210.62,1433; Network Library = DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog = DM_Storage; User ID = FKJ; Password=123456";
//string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source = 192.9.210.62,1433;Initial Catalog = DM_Storage; User ID = Faizan Khan; Password=123456";
```

I have also enabled the sql server settings like

1. Allow remote connection to this server
2. Sql server and windows authentication mode
3. tcp is also enabled, forget to mention it.  and In TCP port it is set to 1443. While the TCP dynamic Ports is set to 61354. Is t his correct?
4. In bound in firewall

Comment: As you're running a named instance, are you *sure* your instance is running on port 1433?

Comment: Check that [TCP is enabled](https://help.dugeo.com/m/Insight/l/438913-troubleshooting-enabling-tcp-ip-in-the-sql-server)

Comment: oh yes tcp is also enabled, forget to mention it.  and In TCP port it is set to 1443. While the TCP dynamic Ports is set to 61354. Is t his correct?

Comment: @Larnu Not sure but when i connect in sql server managemnt studio its server name is "PRO220\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: but in the above connections, which aren't working, you aren't using the instance name (`SQLEXRESS`)` you are specifying the port (`1433`).

Comment: If the dynamic port is set to `61354` then specifying port `1433` isn't going to work. `61354` <> `1433`. Why not pass the instance name?

Comment: How? Can you answer so i can check it?

Comment: Exactly like you did in the one you that succeeded (`localhost\\SQLEXPRESS`) So instead `{IP Address}\\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Oh well it worked but without specifying the port  string sqlConnectionString = "Server = 192.9.210.62\\SQLEXPRESS; " +
     "Database = DCC_Model_Storage; Trusted_Connection=True"; But i didn't change the port in TCP/IP

Comment: @Larnu do you have any idea why this is not accessing via remote? I mean if run above connection string in my pc it work fine but unable to access over LAN.